# Get rid of #Error in Access 2007 group footer report

Tags: ms-access-2007, aggregate-functions

I am creating a report in Access 2007 and I want to do the average, maximum, and minimum of several lab results. When I enter the following in the control source box, I get an #Error message in the group footer when all records being subtotaled are null when displaying the report. How can I get rid of this #Error and have the results return no value at all.

```
=CDbl(Avg([Arsenic]))
```

Thus data might look like this in my report

```
Serum
_______________________
  Arsenic       Iron
     30          10
     30           
     15
____________________
Avg  25          10
Max  30          10
Min  15          10
__________________________
Liver
__________________________
   Arsenic      Iron
                  8
                  0        
                  2
____________________   
Avg #Error        5
Max #Error        8
Min #Error        0
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use just `=Avg([Arsenic])`, it'll be blank.  Whats causing the `#Error` is when `Avg()` returns a blank, `CDbl` has a null input.  If you absolutely must have `CDbl()` for whatever reason, then

```
=IIf(Avg([Arsenic]) Is Null,"",CDbl(Avg([Arsenic])))
```

will work

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. BTW. CDbl is just what the wizard entered. I figured it knew best. I do like having the IIF solution to add to my helpful hints file.